# How to split arguments with a decimal point

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to python and need some help

This is an Example of my problem:

```py
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, *, arg, arg2):
       await ctx.message.delete()
       r = requests.get(f"https://example.api/image?first_text={arg}sec_text={arg2}")
       await ctx.send(r)
```

If I execute the command like this: `{prefix}example argument one text, argument two text`

It should return `example.api/image?first_text=argument one text&sec_text= argument two text`

Comment: what is version of python are you using?

Comment: Python version 3.8.6

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could split an argument. You can use [`.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) to separate [`arguments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) as seen below.

```py
@client.command()
async def split(ctx, *, arg):
    x = arg.split(',')
    for arg in x:
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

**Working Result**:

[image: Result if above works]

Edit: **`But how do I implement it in the api url`**

One thing you could do is check it as a list. Did you notice how I had the previous code loop through the `x` variable? When you `await ctx.send()` or `print` the variable `x` by itself, it gives you a list.

```py
@client.command()
async def split(ctx, *, arg):
    x = arg.split(',')
    print(x)
```

The above code would print: `['arg one', ' arg two', ' another arg']`. With this information, you can look through the list.

```py
@client.command()
async def split(ctx, *, arg):
    x = arg.split(',')
    await ctx.send(f"""
Here's one argument: {x[0]}
And another: {x[1]}
And a third one while we're at it: {x[2]}
""")
```

[image: Result for looking through list]

Comment: But how do I implement it in the api url

Answer (score 0):

you can use asyncio to perform work. You can use **kwargs to pass a dictionary of parameters and values.  When an await is detected in the asynchronous code it relinquishes code execution and the waiting tasking begins to execute.

```
async def func1(**kwargs):
   result=0
   parameters={}
   for key, value in kwargs.items():
       #print(key+":"+str(value))
       parameters[key]=value
   for i in range(parameters['parm1'],parameters['parm2']):
       result+=i
       await asyncio.sleep(0.02)
       print("func1",result)
   return result
async def func2(number, exponent):
   result=0
   for i in range(100):
        num1=pow(number+1,exponent)
       result+=num1
       print("func2",result)
       await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
   return result

dictParms={'parm1':300,'parm2':400}

async def main():
     await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(func1(**dictParms)),
        asyncio.create_task(func2(2,4)),
     )
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, *args):
         await ctx.message.delete()
         for arg in args:
            print(f"{arg}")
```